# Is there a canonical duplicate for `How to play YouTube video in Android` questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

A lot of questions are asked about "How to play YouTube videos in Android, and most of them are answered [using the same link of a certain tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Acode.google.com%2Fp%2Fandroid-youtube-player%2F&tab=newest)

Is there a canonical duplicate for this problem? Or do we need to create one or request merge of the best posts in order to create a dupe target?

Sample questions:

- [Play youtube video In App in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13098147/play-youtube-video-in-app-in-android)
- [Play a youtube video in a videoView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655143/play-a-youtube-video-in-a-videoview)
- [how to integrate youtube android player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488794/how-to-integrate-youtube-android-player)

Comment: Just pick the highest voted one and run with it—oh, they're all 0 score.  Huh.

Comment: Maybe write a question, and a detailed self answer?